# Finding a map which induces isomorphism in Homology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

Let $X$ be a topological space such that $H_i(X)=0$ for all $1<i<n$. Let $H_n(X)=\pi$. Now I want to find a map $f:X \to K(\pi,n)$ such that $H_n(f)$ and $\pi_n(f)$ are isomorphisms. Can anyone give some hints as to how one gets this map. Thank you.

Comment: Use $[X,K(\pi,n)]\cong H^n(X;\pi)\cong \operatorname{hom}(H_n(X),\pi)=\hom(\pi,\pi)$

Comment: You can construct a $K(\pi,n)$ starting from X and attaching cells.

Comment: @iwriteonbananas thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I was actually looking for a construction of the map $f$ rather than $K(\pi,n)$.  But thank you for the hint.

Comment: Well, when you have constructed the EM space from X by adding cells,  you will have in particular a map from X to it...

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Sorry now I understand what you meant. Thank you.